# How to call Oracle CURSOR return procedure in java

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I have this Store Procedure being called in PHP, How can I do this in JDBC ?

```
$searchText = $_POST [ 'searchText1' ];
$sql = 'BEGIN :rc := pa_internal_admin.fn_search_level_1 ( :searchText ); END;';
oci_bind_by_name( $stmt, ":searchText", $searchText, 20 );
```

This is how I'm calling it

```
String dbCall = "{call pa_internal_admin.fn_search_level_1(?,?)}";
proc = dbConn.connection().prepareCall( dbCall );
proc.setString(1, searchText);
proc.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
```

but getting this;

```
SQLException caught: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FN_SEARCH_LEVEL_1' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Need some help Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much the same way as PHP:

```
String dbCall = "{ ? = call pa_internal_admin.fn_search_level_1(?) }";
proc = dbConn.connection().prepareCall( dbCall );
proc.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
proc.setString(2, searchText);
```

Or if you prefer, to be even more similar:

```
String dbCall = "BEGIN ? := pa_internal_admin.fn_search_level_1(?); END;";
```

You tried to call it as a procedure with two parameters, rather than a function with one; you can't arbitrarily change that in your call.

You can get the cursor back with:

```
OracleResultSet rSet = (OracleResultSet) proc.getCursor(1);
```

... and then treat it like any other result set.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alex, this `String dbCall = "{ ?=call pa_internal_admin.fn_search_level_1(?) }";` gives me `SQLException caught: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FN_SEARCH_LEVEL_1' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
`  and the second one gives me `SQLException caught: Non supported SQL92 token at position: 6: BEGIN`

Comment: Thank you Alex after a bit of amendment it worked.   `String dbCall = "{ ? = call pa_internal_admin.fn_search_level_1(?) }";
        proc = dbConn.connection().prepareCall( dbCall );
        proc.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
  proc.setString(2, searchText);`

Comment: @Zed420 - sorry, missed the notification for your first comment. What didn't it like; I'm not sure what you ended up doing differently - it needed the spaces around the `=` ? And I should have been more careful with the `BEGIN` version, I've mixed up the syntax. D'oh.